# System Wide I/O Statistics

Tags: linux, kernel, iostat

In earlier versions of "vmstat", the device minor version was used to determine whether it was a partition or a disk (0 => disk and  >0 => partition)). Am I not correct?
Then, from kernel version 2.6.x some metrics were measured only at the disk-level, and hence the parsing algorithm was based on the number of metrics associated with a device (11 metrics => disk and 4 metrics => partition).

However, in kernel version 2.6.18 there are also 11 metrics for partitions, and RAM drives also have minor device numbers greater than 0. See below:

```
   1    0 ram0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1    1 ram1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1    2 ram2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1    3 ram3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   3    0 hda 364304 44416 9757168 9689046 18080864 19417076 299988386 1952073601 0 167032032 1961762954
   3    1 hda1 170 1105 2566 2352 5 0 10 13 0 1854 2365
   3    2 hda2 364112 43281 9754186 9686147 18080859 19417076 299988376 1952073588 0 167031121 1961760042
 253    0 dm-0 405386 0 9738418 14371284 37409328 0 299274624 2479168190 0 167053870 2493542151
 253    1 dm-1 1906 0 15248 70026 89219 0 713752 70030052 0 70247 70100078
  22   64 hdd 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   2    0 fd0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   9    0 md0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How do I go about separating partitions from disks in this case? My final object is to determine the overall I/O of the system.
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... Well of course that's the first place I looked. I wasn't quite satisfied, though, with the results. But, here's what I discovered:

-- Run `iostat -dkx` and you'll get KBytes/sec read and written to and from every disk in the system. iostat uses quite a complex formula to do it.

-- Take the values of the counters for blocks in and blocks out (`pgpgin` and `pgpgout`) in any 2.6.x kernel and multiply it by 1024, and you get the exact same answer!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at what existing programs do?  dstat is a good one, written in python.  iostat is the old traditional one, and it's -x output only includes disks (and device-mapper devices), not partitions.